# Set selected value in Datalist using Id

Tags: jquery, datalist

I know how to set selected value in Datalist using value,

```
("#taxCodeID").val("value");
```

But I can not use this methode, I want to set the selected value using ID.

In my case I have two Datalists TaxCode and TaxName.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="validate-text">Tax Code</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="TaxCode" list="taxCode" id="taxCodeID"
                       class="form-control ddlCustomercategoryClass" placeholder="--Select Tax Code--" />
        <datalist id="taxCode">
            <option value="---Select Tax Code---"></option>
            <option value="T01" id="1"></option>
            <option value="T02" id="2"></option>
            <option value="T03" id="3"></option>
            <option value="T04" id="4"></option>
        </datalist>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
    <label for="validate-text">Tax Name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="TaxName" list="taxName" id="taxNameID"
                       class="form-control ddlCustomercategoryClass" placeholder="--Select Tax Name--" />
        <datalist id="taxName">
            <option value="---Select Tax Name---"></option>
            <option value="Tax 01" id="1"></option>
            <option value="Tax 02" id="2"></option>
            <option value="Tax 03" id="3"></option>
            <option value="Tax 04" id="4"></option>
        </datalist>
    </div>
</div>
```

here the values are coming from save table, the id field are same but value fields are different.

I am trying set the value of TaxNAme on TaxCode change. I can not use the value to set the other I need to use the Id.

How do I do that?

```
$("#taxCodeID").on('change', function () {

    var taxid = $("#taxCodeID").val(); // getting tax value here

    $("#taxNameID").val(taxid); // setting wrong info

})
```

Fiddle for the above : **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d57Lok6n/)**

Selecting `T01` in TaxCode should set `Tax 01` in TaxName but its setting `T01`.

Comment: You **cannot** have duplicate ids. **id must be unique per document**.

Comment: Its not duplicate ids, As i said the two datalist values are loading from same table `Tax`, it have id,code and name.

Comment: You have each id twice in your code.

Comment: they are coming from same table, thats why i am trying to set the other datalist using the selected id

Comment: The browser doesn't care where they're coming from - each id value in your whole HTML page cannot be used more than once.

Comment: ok, actually the datalist is working perfectly, all i want is a way to set the datalist value as selected using ID parameter

Comment: Again, your HTML is invalid. You **must** fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zL0oqt4f/

```
$("#taxCodeID").on('change', function () {
    var taxid = $("#taxCodeID").val();
    var id;

    $('#taxCode > option').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value") == taxid ){
           id = $(this).attr("id");
        }
    }); //iterate through the taxCode options searching for the taxid

    var value = $('#taxName > #' + id).attr("value"); //based on the id, select from datalist
    $("#taxNameID").val(value); 
})
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider accepting my post as answer, thanks!

Comment: This does not address the invalid HTML due to duplicate ids problem.

Comment: You shouldn't post answers that makes invalid stuff work in the first place. Instead, always address those problems, too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I fixed your duplicate id problem by prefixing the ids in your second datalist. Then it becomes actually very easy. Also, you don't need jQuery for this at all.

```js
taxCodeID.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  if (e.target.value) {
    // get the id of the picked item in the first datalist
    const taxCodePickedId = document.querySelector(`option[value=${e.target.value}]`) ? document.querySelector(`option[value=${e.target.value}]`).id : '';
    // use that id to retrieve the second datalist's matching option
    const taxNameMatch= document.getElementById(`tn${taxCodePickedId}`);
    // make sure there is a matching element in the second list
    if (taxNameMatch) {
      taxNameID.value = taxNameMatch.getAttribute('value');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="validate-text">Tax Code</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="TaxCode" list="taxCode" id="taxCodeID"
                       class="form-control ddlCustomercategoryClass" placeholder="--Select Tax Code--" />
        <datalist id="taxCode">
            <option value="---Select Tax Code---"></option>
            <option value="T01" id="1"></option>
            <option value="T02" id="2"></option>
            <option value="T03" id="3"></option>
            <option value="T04" id="4"></option>
        </datalist>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
    <label for="validate-text">Tax Name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="TaxName" list="taxName" id="taxNameID"
                       class="form-control ddlCustomercategoryClass" placeholder="--Select Tax Name--" />
        <datalist id="taxName">
            <option value="---Select Tax Name---"></option>
            <option value="Tax 01" id="tn1"></option>
            <option value="Tax 02" id="tn2"></option>
            <option value="Tax 03" id="tn3"></option>
            <option value="Tax 04" id="tn4"></option>
        </datalist>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet failed when you didn't pick an item from the list. Fixed that.

Comment: Again, there  is no way you can stay on duplicate ids in whatever solution you use. **Duplicate ids is an absolute no-go.**

Comment: What do you mean? There is no autocomplete of any kind in your sample code either. Maybe you are using a browser that does not support `input` event on select and datalist?

Comment: You can use change event instead, but then the autocomplete will only take place when you blur the first input.